# correct way to mock function from package with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

So this is how I init instance `aws-jwt-verify` on my controller :

```
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';    
const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
     userPoolId: COGNITO_USER_POOL,
     tokenUse: 'access',
     clientId: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
    });
```

then I tried to mock the instance on my unittest using jest like this below :

```
const oauthMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('aws-jwt-verify', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    CognitoJwtVerifier: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        create: () => oauthMock()
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

but I got this error below:

> TypeError: aws_jwt_verify_1.CognitoJwtVerifier.create is not a
> function

what I've done is I tried to modify the mock like this below :

```
jest.mock('aws-jwt-verify', () => ({
  CognitoJwtVerifier: jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      create: oauthMock()
    };
  }),
}));
```

still got same error, is there something I missed here? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem with this :

```
    jest.mock('aws-jwt-verify', () => {
  return {
    CognitoJwtVerifier: { create: jest.fn() },
  };
});
```